# jQuery replacing a <select> in my form, not submitting new data

Tags: jquery

So ill start off with my code:

```
$(function() {
$("#employeeName").keyup(function() {
    var dataString = 'find='+ $("#employeeName").val();  
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "finduser.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response) {
            //On success
            $("#search").html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
 });
});
```

That is my ajax to search for an employees name

My html looks similar to this:

```
<input type='text' id='employeeName' name='employeeName'>
<select id='search' name='id'></select>
<input type='submit'>
```

Basically, it searches the database and returns `<option>`'s with the user's id as the value, and their name as the name, example: `<option value='5'>John Doe</option>`

And this all works great, except that when I select a name and submit the form, it doesn't send the updated option that the person selected, it just sends a blank select(So `$_POST['id']` doesn't exist and throws an error.

How else could I make this work? I tried adding  `onchange="$('#employeeName').val($(this).val())"` to the select so that when they select a name it updates the search box and they can submit the form that way, but that was to no avail..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$_POST['id']` doesn't exist, then your option likely doesn't have a `value`.

If `$('#search').val()` yields an integer, but it isn't there when you submit the form, then either your `<select>` is not a part of the form, or the value gets updated on submit, or you're submitting a `GET` request, so that your value is available through `$_GET['id']`.

1. Verify that your form has the following attribute: `method="POST"`
2. Verify that `$('#the-form').serialize()` contains "id=5".

Comment: I think the problem is that when submitting it with html, it only reads the original page information, I don't think it "sees" that jquery updated the page, if that makes sense

Comment: @TazmanianTad: It doesn't really make sense, no. When you submit a form, you only submit the form values, not the HTML that created the form controls that were used to fill out the values. Your server side can't tell the difference between `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="5" />` and `<select name="id"><option value="5">5</option></select>`, for instance.

Comment: I know, that's not at all what I was trying to say, I just can't explain it in words.

Basically, using `$('#search').val()` returns the correct value, however on form submission, it only sends the value that was set by default (when the page loads), so its almost like when you submit the form, it doesn't see the changes jquery made, it only sees the original page

Comment: @TazmanianTad: What does `$('#my-form').serialize()` yield? Where `#my-form` is your form, of course. What does `$(':input[name=id]').length` yield?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help! (The only thing I changed was taking the onchange out of the select and putting it in its own function, then updating a hidden field with the right id to make it work :)

Comment: @TazmanianTad: well there's definitely something weird going on there, you shouldn't need a hidden field to submit values from a select, regardless of its being updated by AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code in the response : it working for me

```
 $("#search option").remove(); // Remove all <option> child tags.
            $("#search").append($("<option></option>").text("All").val(""));
            $.each(responset, function(index, item) { // Iterates through a
                // collection

                $("#search").append($("<option></option>").text(item).val(item));
```